# how to create a list with access permission checking

Tags: php, mongodb, database-design, database

As title, when I have a content list, but not everybody can see them.
For example:
I have group 1 and group 2
I create a post, only the users in group 1 can see it.
I create another post, only the users in group 2 can see it.

User 1 in group 1, User 2 in group 2.
Then, when user 1 looks at the newest content list, he can only see the post 1.
Then, user user 2 looks at the newest content list, he can only see the post 2.

You can see, different account (user) will see different post in his/her post list. Because I store all posts in one table, and I store the group_id in it, when creating the newest post list for a user, I have to search all newest post and check one by one if the user can see it or not, if there are too many posts which he don't have permission, the performance will be very bad.

Also, the group is not static in some cases, such as: my followers, my friends, if so, I still can't store the user id in post table, and have to calculate their relationship to determine he/she can read this post or not. and again, the post can be with multiple-permission groups (my followers and my friends can see it).

How can I improve it?

BTW, why I don't insert the user_id array in post record, because maybe the number of group users is very big, so I can only save group_id in it.

BTW again, 
I have one SNS website.
I use mongodb database.
I use php.

Answer (score 1):

When user authorizes, store his `group_id` in session data. Then you can use that `group_id` when you generate your menu, make it an extra condition in your database query to get only posts that are allowed to this group to be seen.

If the user is not authorizes, you can use some default `group_id` value to show only posts, allowed for everyone to view.

For complex conditions like the ones you have I'd recommend using `UNION` if you had mysql, but looks like you will simply need to do multiple queries. First, separate all possible different conditions on which content groups should be available to a specific user.

For example: if user can only see content from his group, his friends and people he follows, you can simply do 3 requests (get content list of his group, posts of people he follows and posts of his friends) and then combine that data with PHP and output it. Since all the data is the same (as you said - it all is in `posts` table) you won't need anything fancy here. Just three request and sorting the way you want on php side.

Comment: But the problem is, some group are not static, is active group, such as: my friend can see this post or my followers can see it. so I have to calculate the relationship between them.

Comment: @Elsonwu when any user requests a website you write his permissions into his session data. Then, based on that permissions, you pick content to display.

Comment: Except the system's default groups, different will create different auth group themselves, for example: I have group "My Team", I add you and user B into this group, but others people their will also create their custom group, and again, in the system's default group, everybody has "My Friends", even I write this into the user's session, I still don't create the post list directly, because I have to check if current user is the friend with the post owner, so it's useless to write his permission into his session data.

Comment: You write into session data list of user_id's and list of group_id's  that he can see posts of. No matter what kind of relationship are between, two lists should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it does not work, because the user_ids is too large, in my SNS, the user has several groups, such as "My Classmate", the classmate may come from allover the world, one of classes in my SNS, there are 3000 members in it.

Comment: You need to provide as much details in question, in depth about every aspect of your system. The way you do it - give more info every time I suggest something, I'm sorry I can't help you this way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and sorry for my question not with much detail. but the detail above is my question in my SNS, it's difficult to improve its performance. anyway, thanks again for your answer.